# What design pattern or programming technique to use to separate data flow from control flow?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dataflow

In a distributed system there is one management instance and multiple processing instances. The management instance sends commands to the different processing instances. So the processing nodes need to have some command parsing logic and more logic to act on these commands.

Throughput is important for the processing instances so the actual data flow should be impacted as little as possible.

Is there a design pattern or programming technique I can use to clearly separate data and control flow in the processing instances while keeping performance of the data flow as high as possible?

Edit:

The general implementation as of now is like follows: There are N processing threads, pooled, and a single control thread. At least virtually, they all have their own private data structures. What the control thread can do is change the actual thread function. I see design patterns as general, high level designs which I don't have to follow closely, but still I am interested if there is such a high level design that minimizes the disturbance of the processing threads.
I'm targeting C++17, if that should be of any concern.

Comment: this question is too broad to be answered, but you may want to look into thread pools, command pattern, pubsub pattern...

Comment: @flowit it's a good question. Could you provide some examples to show how do you understand both concepts to make sure that people will be able to answer your question?

Comment: Maybe this should be asked on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com ? Agree with @EirNym - It's a good question

Comment: I like your question.  In the embedded telecom hardware control software  development, we refer to 'command' and 'status' channels as north and south, and data flows east and west.  Typically, east/west data traffic is NOT handled by any control or monitoring software, nor does it enter/exit the control processor.  Instead, dedicated hardware (or sometimes a peculiar architecture processor) runs it faster than you might imagine.  I think your question leads to discussion of how to keep data (east/west) out of the control processor, and minimize the software running in the east/west equipment.